# Prove that, if $f(x)<a$ for $x\in I_1$ and $g(x)<a$ for $x\in I_2$, then $\sup I_1\geq\sup I_2$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $I$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$ and let us consider two functions
$$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow I\quad\text{and}\quad
g:\mathbb R\rightarrow I.$$

Let $f(x)\leq g(x)$, $\forall x\in \mathbb R$. Prove that, if 
$$f(x)<a\in I,\;\forall x\in I_1$$  and
$$g(x)<a\in I,\;\forall x\in I_2$$then $\sup I_1\geq\sup I_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\sup I_1 <\sup I_2$

Set $\varepsilon =\sup I_2-\sup I_1>0$. Thus $\exists x_0\in I_2,\,\sup I_1=\sup I_2-\varepsilon<x_0\le\sup I_2$

$x_0\in I_2\Rightarrow g(x_0)<a\Rightarrow f(x_0)<a$

$x_0>\sup I_1\Rightarrow x_0\notin I_1\Rightarrow f(x_0)\ge a$

We get a contradiction.

Comment: Why $x_0 >\sup I_1$?

Comment: @Mark According to $\sup$ properties we have the following for a set $E$ which have a $\sup$:
$(i)\,\,\,\forall x\in E,\,x\le\sup E$
$(ii)\,\,\,\forall \varepsilon >0,\,\exists x_0\in E,\, \sup E-\varepsilon <x_0$
If we suppose that $\sup I_1<\sup I_2$ we can take $\varepsilon=\sup I_2-\sup I_1>0$. We apply $(i)$ and $(ii)$ for the set $I_2$. Thus:
$\exists x_0\in I_2,\,\sup I_2-\varepsilon <x_0\le\sup I_2$
But $\sup I_2-\varepsilon =\sup I_1$. Thus $\exists x_0\in I_2,\,\sup I_1<x_0\le\sup I_2$